# Run shell script inside ssh session inside Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run a complete script while the ssh session is live instead of single commands.

Here is my current code:

```
sh "ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@IPV4_DNS uptime"
sh "ssh -v ubuntu@IPV4_DNS docker pull X:${BUILD_NUMBER}"
sh "ssh -v ubuntu@IPV4_DNS docker rm -f test"
sh "ssh -v ubuntu@IPV4_DNS docker run --name=test -d -p 3000:3000X:${BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

The desired code is something like this, but the following **doesn't work:***

```
sh "ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@IPV4_DNS uptime"
sh ''' ssh -v ubuntu@IPV4_DNS docker pull X:${BUILD_NUMBER}
       && docker rm -f test && docker run --name=test -d -p 3000:3000X:${BUILD_NUMBER} 
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
ssh something here && something else && another one
```

runs `something here` in the `ssh` session, and `something else` and `another one` locally.  You want to add quotes to pass the entire command line to `ssh`.

```sh
sh "ssh -tt -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@IPV4_DNS uptime"
sh """ssh -v ubuntu@IPV4_DNS 'docker pull X:${BUILD_NUMBER} &&
    docker rm -f test &&
    docker run --name=test -d -p "3000:3000X:${BUILD_NUMBER}"'
"""
```

I switched to triple double quotes instead of triple single quotes, assuming you want Jenkins to expand `${BUILD_NUMBER}` for you.

The original question asked about Bash, but for the record, you are running `sh` here, not Bash.  If you wanted to use Bash features in a Jenkinsfile, you can add a shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar as the very first line of the command.  But that's not necessary here; all these commands are simple and completely POSIX. (Maybe see also [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash))